# App crashing while collecting reports in google doc

Tags: android, acra

Trying to collect app crash reports in google doc using ACRA but had a problem in AppCrashReports.java file ,here i am using won variable content in crash report.but app crashing with out starting the application here i am placing the logcat.

```
    05-17 03:56:06.478: I/dalvikvm(738): Could not find method org.acra.ErrorReporter.getInstance, referenced from method com.lisnx.util.AppCrashReports.onCreate
05-17 03:56:06.478: W/dalvikvm(738): VFY: unable to resolve static method 12707: Lorg/acra/ErrorReporter;.getInstance ()Lorg/acra/ErrorReporter;
05-17 03:56:06.478: D/dalvikvm(738): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
05-17 03:56:06.488: I/dalvikvm(738): Could not find method org.acra.ACRA.init, referenced from method com.lisnx.util.AppCrashReports.onCreate
05-17 03:56:06.488: W/dalvikvm(738): VFY: unable to resolve static method 12706: Lorg/acra/ACRA;.init (Landroid/app/Application;)V
05-17 03:56:06.488: D/dalvikvm(738): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0033
05-17 03:56:06.488: D/AndroidRuntime(738): Shutting down VM
05-17 03:56:06.488: W/dalvikvm(738): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.acra.ErrorReporter
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.lisnx.util.AppCrashReports.onCreate(AppCrashReports.java:21)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:968)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3696)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1062)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-17 03:56:06.497: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed this issue by "exporting" the "Android private Libraries" in the project. still suspect this is an issue of ADT 22.

goto your project properties, java build path, order and export, and check "Android private Libraries".

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have the ACRA library in your app (at runtime). Add it into your apk.

Comment: I have the same problem, seems like to be some issue of ADT 22. I do have acra in classpath. if i do an "ant debug install", it works perfectly.